# Swift pushed Viewcontroller error when retrieving data with Viewmodel and Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel

I have two ViewControllers that I use to show data from Firebase. In the first ViewController I can show the data that I want when I'm calling the ViewModel. When I press on a button in the first ViewController I get navigated to the second ViewController with:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

I have a User Object that I retrieve from the ViewModel that retrieves data from Firebase:

```
    userRetrievedData = userViewModel.user
```

Viewmodel:

```
let firstName = document.get("firstName") as? String ?? ""
self.user = Account(firstName: firstName)
```

Before I could retrieve data in the second ViewController but now it gives me an error.

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

On this line I get the error in the second Viewcontroller, while the same line in the first Viewcontroller works:

```
userRetrievedData.firstName!
```

Why does it gives this error in second ViewController and not the first?

Declarations inside the ViewController are the same:

```
var userRetrievedData = User()
var userViewModel = UserViewModel()
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your second ViewController? Where do you declare the `userRetrievedData` object?

Comment: I declare at the top of both the ViewControllers, I edited my code.

Comment: Ok, so looks like the problem is that you are initializing the `userRetrievedData` only in the first view controller, and not the other. You should initialize the instance in the second view controller before referencing its attributes.

Comment: I have the code in both ViewControllers so thats not the problem. Both declarations and method to call the viewmodel. I made a typo ViewController instead of ViewModel edited the post now

Comment: It is the same as the last part of the post. Only instead of "Declerations inside the ViewController" I had "Declerations inside the ViewModel" The code is meant for the ViewController. The code I referred to are the initializing in the ViewController.

Comment: You should take a look at using a segue to move between viewControllers. You can also pass data using the segue and it makes going back to the first viewController really easy. There are a bunch of examples there here on SO as well as youtube tutorials and internet tutorials as well. As far as your error goes, your first viewController populated the `userRetrievedData` with data which is why this `userRetrievedData.firstName!` works. In your second viewController, that var is probably not populated with data e.g. var userRetrievedData = User(), which it why is crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the object from first to the second? and I would use optional variable in the second controller not intialized so that it gets it from the first one.

and the you can do in the first controller

```
secondViewController.userRetrievedData = userRetrievedData
navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

in the second controller

```
userRetrievedData?.firstName
```

Comment: I got it working by passing it from the first viewcontroller to the second. But why can't I retrieve data again in the second viewcontroller via the viewcontroller and firebase and only the first.

Comment: Also the optional part is not working I must use an exclamtion ! to get it working

Comment: You can do that if thats what you want to do but remeber there is a cost associated with making calls on your side as well as user is paying for bandwith for the same data

Comment: Ussually force unreapping is not a good idea since it can crash the app, try using guard statements

guard let firstName = userRetrievedData?.firstName else {}

Comment: No its fine this way but I was just interested why it isn't working by calling the data again in a different viewcontroller. I will try it with guard statements